# Why are some characters garbled on twitter?

Tags: firefox, unicode, twitter

When viewing my twitter feed on my PC browser ( Firefox 20.0.1 on Windows Vista 32bit) certain characters come through garbled.

For example, this tweet to me:-

https://twitter.com/ryanmurrant/status/324190344939991040

On my Android phone the tweet shows a Thumb-up symbol, but in my PC browser I see it as a small square containing the numbers 01F44D across two lines.

I thought that maybe my PC wasn't displaying UTF8 correctly, but I can view the example symbols on this page without any problem:-

http://thenextweb.com/2008/09/16/twitterkeys-enhance-your-twitter-conversations/

Comment: 0x01xxxx is very high in the Unicode range; most fonts available on desktop/laptop machines don't include that range, while mobile phones do support it for emoji and similar. You might consider trying a font which represents more than usual of the full Unicode range; in particular, Quivira (http://www.quivira-font.com/) apparently includes the emoticon range, and therefore might be able to display that character where most fonts can't. Worth a try, at any rate --

Comment: Works for me on Firefox / Win 7. Element appears to be <p class="js-tweet-text tweet-text "><a href="/RobSharp" class="twitter-atreply pretty-link" dir="ltr"><s>@</s><b>RobSharp</b></a> </p>

Perhaps you have a script blocker on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this with the help of this website:-

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f44d/index.htm

It told me that the font Symbola ( http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) contains this character. I've installed it and it was immediately viewable in my browser.